# Support both beta & production version in same database

Tags: sql-server

We are having our product which having SQL Server as a back-end database. Now we are having a problem statement that whenever a new version is deployed it must be used by a few user's and other's will continue using older versions.

Application side we can maintain two instances but database we can't do just like that because transaction & master data should be single. Code isolation in the database is not possible.

Any inputs?

Note: Application having configurations which were maintained in the database.

Comment: There isn't even a question here. Just a vague explanation that you can't handle different versions of the application within a multi tenant database. What are you expecting as an answer?

Comment: This problem admits no free lunch. If you are changing the underlying data structure, there is no automatic way to go from A to B without any interruption -- there cannot be two skies. If you are only changing the logic, it's doable in many ways. I've had some success with a custom schema that contains views and stored procedures, and changing the default schema of a login as appropriate. One application is accessing `old.View`, while the other accesses `new.View`, even though both use `View`. Or you could use separate databases with aliases pointing to the master DB.

Comment: I know it's a complex part to handle. But I want to know about the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

We have three ways of supporting database changes to allow rolling out versions of the application. These solutions work because we only allow stored procedure access to the tables.

1. For minor changes, like adding a parameter to an existing search, we make sure the change is done in a non-breaking way. For example, when adding a new parameter to a stored procedure, we default it to a value that maintains the existing behavior.

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [DoSearch]
       @NAME VARCHAR(50),
       @BIRTHDAY DATE = NULL -- Defaults value means it's optional
   AS ...
   ```

NOTE: When the old code calls this stored procedure, `@BIRTHDAY` is not passed. But, since it has a default value, SQL is happy.

2. For bigger changes (like a change a resultset) we create add a version number to the stored procedure and call that from the updated application:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [DoSearch_v2]
       @NAME VARCHAR(50)
   AS
       SELECT FIELD1, 
              FIELD2, -- different data type than v1 of stored procedure
              FIELD3, -- a field not returned by v1 of stored procedure
   ```
3. For major revisions...

We have our database projects such that tables exist in one database and the stored procedures exist in another. This means we can have two very different versions of stored procedures but point to the same data.

```
    CREATE DATABASE [App_Data] -- Only has tables
    CREATE DATABASE [App_SPROCS_V1] -- References [App_Data]
    CREATE DATABASE [App_SPROCS_V2] -- References [App_Data]
```

The Website for Customer-A uses the 'old' application, and therefore points to [App_SPROCS_V1].

The Website for Customer-B uses the 'new' application, and therefore points to [App_SPROCS_V2].

This works because, even for major upgrades, we rarely make changes to the data structure that cannot be done in a non-breaking way (like adding a column or even tables). We also only have a dozen deployments -- if you had a thousand, you'd want to do something different.

An example of when we did this is when we upgraded our website from .NET 4.x to .NET Core. We took the opportunity to do a ton of house cleaning and re-implementation of features. We didn't want to "bend" the current stored procedures so we created all new ones in [APP_SPROCS_V2].

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how to have two versions of your system sharing a database - the old code and the new code? If there aren't any schema alterations, this shouldn't be a problem. If schema alterations are additive (new views, new tables, new columns with appropriate defaults) generally that's fine too.

For other schema alterations, you'll need to write them in such a way that the new code understands the old schema, get everyone from the old code onto the new code, then remove any remnants of the old schema.

There are tricks possible. E.g. if you've rearranged which tables a given set of data is in, defining a view that resembles the old way of storing it will allow old and new code to access it - and with triggers this can work for tables being written to as well (but beware performance issues).

It's difficult to be more specific as it'll depend very much on what your application does, what's changed between the two versions, and how much spare capacity you have on your DB to do the work arounds.